# Result of task invocation on a grain in Orleans

Tags: c#, .net-core, actor, orleans

I apologize for the long question. I have been experimenting with Orleans to know about its various properties and these questions are logically under one umbrella.

---

The first test involved making request from client to a specific grain every 1 second while the grain takes 10 seconds to execute the requests. The code is this:

```
// client code
while (1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client giving another request");
    double temperature = random.NextDouble() * 40;
    var sensor = client.GetGrain<ITemperatureSensorGrain>(500);
    Task t = sensor.SubmitTemperatureAsync((float)temperature);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Status);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }

// grain code
public Task SubmitTemperatureAsync(float temperature)
{
    long grainId = this.GetPrimaryKeyLong();
    Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} outer received temperature: {temperature}");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} outer complete");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The console output is:

```
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer received temperature: 32.29987    <------------ print statement inside grain
Client giving another request     <--------------------- client continues
Task Status - WaitingForActivation  <------------------- client isn't blocked
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Client giving another request
Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer complete
```

As grains in Orleans are single threaded, only first request is invoked and rest requests are queued on the grain side. My questions for this part are: -

In normal C#, when an async method is called, it continues on the main thread till it hits the await statement when it starts the awaited expression as another Task and returns that Task. So, the caller is blocked till the await statement is hit. Similarly, here too the client should be blocked for 10s after which the first request to grain returns a Task. However, that doesn't happen. The client is continuing to schedule tasks without getting blocked.

- So, is the call to grains from client `FireAndForget`?
- If yes, then how do they get back the Task object?
- Is there any kind of blocking involved when client makes a call to a grain object and runtime brings Task object back to the client?

---

The second test involved making request from a grain to a grain in which the second grain waits 10 seconds before returning. The code is this:

```
// client code
while (1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client giving another request");
    double temperature = random.NextDouble() * 40;
    var sensor = client.GetGrain<ITemperatureSensorGrain>(500);
    Task t = sensor.SubmitTemperatureAsync((float)temperature);
    Console.WriteLine("Client Task Status - "+t.Status);

    // make client sleep for a long time after the first request
    // because we don't want any more requests from the client
    Thread.Sleep(1000000000);
}

// outer-grain (ITemperatureSensorGrain) code
public async Task SubmitTemperatureAsync(float temperature)
{
    long grainId = this.GetPrimaryKeyLong();
    Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} outer received temperature: {temperature}");

    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grain sending another request");
        ITempBGrain sensor = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<ITempBGrain>(400);
        // await sensor.SubmitTempBAsync(temperature);
        Task t = sensor.SubmitTempBAsync(temperature);
        Console.WriteLine("Grain Task Status - "+t.Status);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

// inner-grain (ITempBGrain) code
public Task SubmitTempBAsync(float temperature)
{
    long grainId = this.GetPrimaryKeyLong();
    Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} internal received temperature: {temperature}");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} internal complete");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The console output is:

```
Client giving another request
Client Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer received temperature: 10.36764
Grain sending another request       <-------------- Outer grain prints
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation 
Grain sending another request  <----------- Inner grain doesn't print
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
warn: Orleans.Runtime.CallbackData[100157]
      Response did not arrive on time in 00:00:30 for message: Request *cli/015ba7a5@d4cdc7ab->S127.0.0.1:30000:0*grn/6424EE47/000001f4 #17: . Target History is: <S127.0.0.1:30000:0:*grn/6424EE47/000001f4:>. About to break its promise.
Grain sending another request
Grain Task Status - WaitingForActivation
```

What I see here is something similar to what happened with client in the first experiment. So, those questions are still there. However, here there is one more strange thing happening. The console output of inner grain appears nowhere. **Why is the inner grain not executing?** If I enable the commented out line in outer-grain code, and await the inner grain task, the following output appears which seems valid.

```
Client giving another request
Client Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer received temperature: 6.332514
Grain sending another request
400 internal received temperature: 6.332514
400 internal complete
Grain sending another request
400 internal received temperature: 6.332514
```

Comment: You are not awaiting the task `Task t = sensor.SubmitTemperatureAsync((float)temperature);` should be `await sensor.SubmitTemperatureAsync((float)temperature);` or call `await t` somewhere after.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Once the task is sent to a grain in Orleans (in this case the inner-grain), the outer grain need not await it. The task in inner grain should run no matter what.

Comment: I think you don't understand how async works. Orleans is all about async execution, thats why all grains return Task or Task<T>. `Thread.Sleep(10000);` blocks the thread, `Task.Delay(10000)` doesn't. On top of that,  `Thread.Sleep(1000000000)` is `>` then `00:30` ;)

Comment: Also is the client code in the same application/process as the grains? However mixing async and sync code is a no-go, it screams for trouble. Remember, awaiting a task is not the same as starting a new thread (or executing code on some background thread [from the pool])

Comment: I am confused. What I know is that in Orleans, each grain runs on its own thread which is separate from the client thread. Request from one grain to another is a form of RPC. awaiting is just used to block the calling grain thread till the request in the called grain completes. I don't think it's necessary. 

This can be proved by the first test of my experiment above where I don't await in client, yet requests are complete in grain. Also, in the second part if I modify and remove the while loop from outer grain, all tasks execute properly without any need for await.

Comment: Also, I know that this is a bad coding practice. As I said, I am doing this for experimenting.

Comment: No-no, common misconception. Each grain **DO NOT RUN ON ITS OWN THREAD**. Orleans only guarantees that a grain will only be processed by a single thread (hence: No locking mechanism is required for thread synchronization). Orleans uses the async feature of .NET Core. It will process a grain until an async operation happens. Then it returns the thread to the thread-pool. This thread can be used by another grain to process data until the async operation is complete. When its complete, it resumes. its not necessary the same thread (but its the same context)

Comment: Then experiment it with full async. The async equivalent of `Thread.Sleep(n)` is `await Task.Delay(n)`!!!

Comment: Thank you, @Tseng! @Avinash Kumar, your question has many parts to it but I want to focus on one: "In normal C#, when an async method is called, it continues on the main thread till it hits the await statement when it starts the awaited expression as another Task and returns that Task. ". This is still true in Orleans, since it runs on .NET, however please note that you are calling an interface and not directly calling your grain class. If Orleans blocked that remote call until the first await then your system would be extremely, extremely slow and would not scale

Comment: @Tseng is correct: grains do not run in their own thread, they are *effectively single-threaded* which means that only one thread is executing your grain activation's code at any particular point in time. Having one thread per grain activation would be very expensive and would not scale well.

Comment: @ReubenBond @Tseng ... I think I have got the answer to the second part of my question. The outer grain is continuously occupying the execution thread and isn't giving a chance to the inner grain to execute. When I await inside while loop (or remove while loop altogether, call a Task on inner grain and execute without awaiting), the thread becomes available to the inner grain to execute.   Is this correct?

     
@Tseng... what did you mean by `Thread.Sleep(1000000000) is > then 00:30`. What's the significance of 30s ?

Comment: Ignore that, confused it with the client part code in your example

Comment: @ReubenBond..  Regarding the first part, I am still unclear. So, what happens when a grain or client calls a method of another grain? The call doesn't seem to be blocking as the client progresses forward even before the task starts on the target grain. So, is it like Orleans runtime enqueues a Task to target grain and returns a reference to the Task to the caller and the caller is blocked till this roundtrip happens?     

  In that way, it will be different from normal C# where the caller is blocked till the first await is encountered.

Comment: @Tseng... Now, I get your question about "Also is the client code in the same application/process as the grains?". Yes, the client and silo are started by the same process. So, is it that the Orleans runtime creates just 2 threads - one used by client and another by grains? And the outer grain is hogging the second thread, not allowing first thread to execute.

Can we specify the number of threads Orleans runtime can create within a process or that is determined dynamically by Orleans?

Comment: Threads are managed by ThreadPool and  by orleans internal scheduler. grains run on the internal scheduler and usually has a low number of threads (CPUs * 2 iirc, can be configured though). ThreadPool is usually managed by the runtime. awaiting doesnt mean starting a thread. its mostly used for I/O operations (which don't require a thread or cpu, since they are controlled via I/O competition ports). But the context switches happen and when you are blocking in a context while an async executes and wants to get back to that context, you may end up in a deadlock

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html may be useful

Comment: @ReubenBond... Forgive me but I am still unclear on "Is a request to another grain blocking?". It isn't blocking in my example. The client proceeds even though the grain hasn't started execution. You said something similar earlier about "interface being called and the call wasn't blocking". 

However, we do get back a Task object (status WaitingForActivation) for every request (even if we don't await). So, does Orleans runtime enqueue a Task to target grain and return a reference to the Task and the caller is blocked till this roundtrip happens? Any related blogs are appreciated.

Comment: Please also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664117/difference-between-method-call-in-normal-c-sharp-and-orleans/51664341#51664341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Part**
No, there is no blocking when a call to a grain is made. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664117/difference-between-method-call-in-normal-c-sharp-and-orleans) post further clears what happens when a grain call is made.

**Second Part**
While it is correct that grains are single threaded, it is wrong to assume that every grain has its own thread in Orleans. As @Tseng says `Orleans uses the async feature of .NET Core. It will process a grain until an async operation happens. Then it returns the thread to the thread-pool. This thread can be used by another grain to process data until the async operation is complete. When its complete, it resumes. its not necessary the same thread (but its the same context)`. The first grain is blocking the thread giving no chance for the second grain to execute.

Thanks Tseng and Reuben Bond for making things clear.