# Ensuring message sequence in Orleans in a pipelined execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, orleans

I have three grains (A, B and C) doing different jobs in a pipeline. GrainA will pass the result to grainB, and grainB will pass the result to grainC. I want to guarantee sequential message sending between successive grains which can be achieved by below.

```
// client code
foreach（var i in list）
{
    await grainA.job(i);
}

//grain A code
async Task job(var i)
{
    DoSomeWorkA(i);
    await grainB.job(i);
}

//grain B code
async Task job(var i)
{
    DoSomeWorkB(i);
    await grainC.job(i);
}

//grain C code
async Task job(var i)
{
    DoSomeWorkC(i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However, the problem with this code is that there is no pipelining. grainA is given the net object only when the current object goes through all the grainB and grainC (because of the await statement). One way to get pipelining is not use await and directly send objects one after the other. However, that leads to out-of-order delivery as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664117/difference-between-method-call-in-normal-c-sharp-and-orleans).

**I want to let the execution be fully pipelined, which means grainA continues on to its next job when grainB receives the result from grainA. However, message ordering is also important as I send some control messages. How to do that in Orleans?**

Comment: So you don't want the different jobs to run concurrently, but you don't want them to run sequentially.  So what do you want?  What operations can be reordered with respect to each other, and what operations can't be?

Comment: Think of it as a workflow involving different operators which are to be executed one after the other. An operator adds something to the object which later operators might need. Therefore, the operators must run sequentially but in a pipelined way. i.e. When object-1 is at grainC, object-2 should be at grainB, object-3 at grainA.

Comment: Are these operators stateful? Why does the return order matter if they are just returning all the way up the stack to the original caller? If there's some kind of sequencing which is important, it's not present in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make highly concurrent systems easy to program and reason about, Orleans limits the parallelism and concurrency of each grain (the unit of computation & state) to 1. That means that at most one message will be processed concurrently and at most one thread will be executing a given grain activation's code at any point in time.

This greatly simplifies what the developer needs to concentrate on since there is no longer a need for thread synchronization primitives like locks.

However, the behavior is configurable. If you do not want this default, 'safe', behavior then you can mark a grain as `[Reentrant]` or mark individual methods as `[AlwaysInterleave]` on the grain's interface.

This allows for many messages to be processed concurrently. At each `await` point in the grain method, execution is yielded back to the scheduler and the scheduler can begin processing another message. The scheduler still ensures single-threadedness for each grain activation, so locks are still not needed, but messages are allowed to interleave at those `await` points (i.e, cooperative multitasking). This means that the developer now needs to consider how internal state might be mutated by other requests between these `await` points.

For more information, see the [Reentrancy page in the Orleans documentation](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/Reentrant-Grains.html).

In order to increase parallelism (for CPU-bound tasks), a developer can either use [Stateless Workers](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Core-Features/StatelessWorker.html) or [External Tasks](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/External-Tasks-and-Grains.html) via `Task.Run` or similar.

Note also that messages sent from grain activation A to grain activation B will always be sent in-order regardless of concurrency configuration. Likewise for results sent from B to A. Note that it still becomes harder to reason about the order of messages once concurrency is increased, however, since a second call to B may finish before the first call and therefore its result will be sent earlier, also. This means that the results may appear to be received out-of-order. I imagine that this is what you would expect, though.

Comment: Oh. that may raise a problem. Please tell me if my below understanding is correct.

`Assume I use [Reentrant]. If grain-A makes request-1 to grain-B and awaits that, then it is free to make request-2 too to grain-B. Now in grain-B, the request-2 might arrive earlier than request-1. Thus, the message order is no more intact.`

Comment: No, I said that the requests are always in order. It's the replies that might not be in order because the requests may take different times to process (and I assume you're doing some awaiting so that execution is yielded and there may be some unordered interleaving within a request). What kind of behaviour are you trying to achieve? Do these grains have some kind of state? In other words, can you scale out by using stateless workers or multiple grains at each stage?

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question. I'm interested to better understand your scenario.

Comment: We are trying to design workflow processing engine using grains. A workflow can contain many operators like SQL statements or machine learning models.  Each operator can be represented by a grain (however, for parallelism sake, we can have multiple grains per operator). A series of rows flow through this workflow and the operators act on them.

Currently, we don’t see operators as having state (but it is very early to say that we won’t be needing state).

Comment: We aren’t returning anything to the previous operators (as rows travel ahead in the workflow and are finally put into a stream). So, what we care about is requests execution at callee being in same order as being invoked by caller. However, are you sure about requests being in order? Because, in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664117/difference-between-method-call-in-normal-c-sharp-and-orleans), we saw that execution at grain wasn’t in order of being called at client (i.e. message sequence isn’t preserved by Orleans). Or does await change this behavior?

Comment: Order is preserved, however if you send messages 1, 2, and 3 to a grain, it's possible that the silo it's activated on crashes after message 2 and the grain is reactivated for message 3. By not awaiting each message, you can ensure that 1 & 2 are processed before 3. The messages to the defunct silo will not be automatically resent. So I'd suggest either not enabling interleaving (and hence processing one message at a time) or using Streams to achieve the desired behaviour or using a custom solution (perhaps involving sequence numbers) to ensure each grain in the graph processes messages in the

Comment: Typo: By not awaiting each message, you can *not* ensure that 1 & 2 are processed before 3