# Understanding single-threaded nature of Orleans grains

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, actor, orleans

I have the following code snippet of a client and a grain in Orleans. **(Although the recommended way to develop in Orleans is to await Tasks, the following code doesn't await at some points purely for experimentation purposes)**

```
// client code
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client giving another request");   
    double temperature = random.NextDouble() * 40;   
    var grain = client.GetGrain<ITemperatureSensorGrain>(500);
    Task t = sensor.SubmitTemperatureAsync((float)temperature);
    Console.WriteLine("Client Task Status - "+t.Status);
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}

// ITemperatureSensorGrain code
public async Task SubmitTemperatureAsync(float temperature)
{
   long grainId = this.GetPrimaryKeyLong();
   Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} outer received temperature: {temperature}");

   Task x = SubmitTemp(temperature); // SubmitTemp() is another function in the same grain
   x.Ignore();
   Console.WriteLine($"{grainId} outer received temperature: {temperature} exiting");
}

public async Task SubmitTemp(float temp)
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Internal function getting awaiting task {i}");
       await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

The output when I run the above code is the following:

```
Client giving another request
Client Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer received temperature: 23.79668
Internal function getting awaiting task 0
500 outer received temperature: 23.79668 exiting
Internal function getting awaiting task 1
Internal function getting awaiting task 2
Internal function getting awaiting task 3
Internal function getting awaiting task 4
Client giving another request
Client Task Status - WaitingForActivation
500 outer received temperature: 39.0514
Internal function getting awaiting task 0  <------- from second call to SubmitTemp
500 outer received temperature: 39.0514 exiting
Internal function getting awaiting task 5  <------- from first call to SubmitTemp
Internal function getting awaiting task 1
Internal function getting awaiting task 6
Internal function getting awaiting task 2
Internal function getting awaiting task 7
Internal function getting awaiting task 3
Internal function getting awaiting task 8
Internal function getting awaiting task 4
Internal function getting awaiting task 9
```

The output makes sense from the perspective of a normal .Net application. If I can take help from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567128/result-of-task-invocation-on-a-grain-in-orleans), what is happening here is that:

1. Client makes a call to `ITemperatureSendorGrain` and proceeds ahead. When the `await` is hit, the client thread is returned to the threadpool.
2. `SubmitTemperatureAsync` receives the request and calls a local async function `SubmitTemp`.
3. `SubmitTemp` prints statement corresponding to i=0 after which point it hits await. Await causes the rest of the `for loop` to be scheduled as a continuation of the awaitable (Task.Delay) and the control returns to the calling function `SubmitTemperatureAsync`. Note here that the thread isn't returned to the threadpool when it encounters await in `SubmitTemp` function. The thread control is actually returned to the calling function `SubmitTemperatureAsync`. So, a `turn`, as defined in Orleans docs, ends when the top level method encounters an await. When a turn ends, the thread is returned to the threadpool.
4. The calling function doesn't wait for the task to finish and exits.
5. When the awaitable in `SubmitTemp` returns after 1s, it gets a thread from the threadpool and schedules the rest of the `for loop` on it.
6. When the awaitable in client code returns, it makes another call to the same grain and another round of `for loop` is scheduled corresponding to the second call to `SubmitTemp`.

**My first question** is have I correctly described what's happening in the code, especially about the thread not being returned to the thread pool when await is hit in the function `SubmitTemp`.

---

According to single-threaded nature of grains, at any time only one thread will be executing a grain's code. Also, once a request to a grain begins execution, it will be completed fully before the next request is taken up (called `chunk based execution` in the Orleans docs). On a high-level, this is true for the above code because the next call to `SubmitTemperatureAsync` will happen only when the current call to the method exits.

However, `SubmitTemp` was actually a sub-function of `SubmitTemperatureAsync`. Although `SubmitTemperatureAsync` exited, `SubmitTemp` is still executing and while it does that, Orleans allowed another call to `SubmitTemperatureAsync` to execute. Doesn't this violate the single-threaded nature of Orleans grain **is my second question**?

---

Consider that `SubmitTemp` in its `for loop` needs to access some data members of the grain class. So, the `ExecutionContext` will be captured when await is encountered and when `Task.Delay(1000)` returns, the captured `ExecutionContext` will be passed to the scheduling of the remainder `for loop` on a thread. Because `ExecutionContext` is passed, the remainder `for loop` will be able to access the data members in spite of running on a different thread. This is something which happens in any normal .Net asynchronous application.

**My third question** is about `SynchronizationContext`. I did a cursory search in the Orleans repository but couldn't find any implementation of `SynchronizationContext.Post()`, which leads me to believe that no `SynchronizationContext` is required to run Orleans methods. Can anyone confirm this? If this isn't true, and a `SynchronizationContext` is required, wouldn't the parallel execution of the various invocations of `SubmitTemp` (as shown in the above code), run the risk of ending in a deadlock (if someone holds on to the `SynchronizationContext` and doesn't release it)?

Comment: "So, the ExecutionContext will be captured when await is encountered" No, it's the SynchronizationContext that's captured and used for the purpose described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Question 1: Is the described execution flow an accurate representation of what's happening?

Your description looks roughly correct to me, but here's a few finer points:

- Whether or not there's a thread pool is an implementation detail.
- 'Turns' are each synchronous portion of work scheduled on the activation's `TaskScheduler`.
- Therefore, a turn ends whenever a execution has to be yielded back to the `TaskScheduler`.
- That could be because an `await` was hit which wasn't synchronously completed, or maybe the user isn't using `await` at all and is programming using `ContinueWith` or custom awaitables.
- A turn could be ended from a non-top-level method, eg if the code was changed to `await SubmitTemp(x)` instead of `.Ignoring()` it, then the turn would end when the `Task.Delay(...)` was hit inside `SubmitTemp(x)`.

## Question 2: Does the example program demonstrate a violation of the single-threadedness guarantee?

No, there is only ever a single thread executing the grain's code at a given time. *However*, that 'thread' has to split its time between the various tasks which are scheduled on the activation's `TaskScheduler`. i.e, there will *never* be a time where you suspend the process and discover that two threads are executing your grain's code at the same time.

As far as the runtime is concerned, the processing of your message ends when the `Task` (or other awaitable type) returned from the top level method completes. Until that occurs, no new messages will be scheduled for execution on your activation. Background tasks spawned from your methods are always allowed to interleave with other tasks.

.NET allows child tasks to be attached to their parent task. In that case, the parent task only completes when all child tasks complete. This is not the default behavior, however, and it's generally suggested that you avoid opting-in to this behavior (eg, by passing `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`).

If you did make use of that behavior (please don't), then you would see your activation loop on the first call to `SubmitTemp()` indefinitely, and no more messages will be processed.

## Question 3: Does Orleans use `SynchronizationContext`?

Orleans does *not* use `SynchronizationContext`. Instead, it uses custom `TaskScheduler` implementations. See [`ActivationTaskScheduler.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/1ff7e3a6c81bbe35ed4087856a3f455e46c4b7c0/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/ActivationTaskScheduler.cs). Each activation has its own `ActivationTaskScheduler` and all messages are scheduler using that scheduler.

Regarding the follow-on question, the `Task` instances (each one representing a synchronous piece of work) which are scheduled against the activation are inserted into the same queue and so they are allowed to interleave, but the `ActivationTaskScheduler` is only executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: Could you please check my answer? I'm afraid my answer is wrong. 1. Is it true, that .Ignore() escapes the Orleans' scheduler? 2. I'm sure misunderstood what "turn" means, I've read the docs and the WP as turn is all the code from the beginning a call until it returns (with several awaits and tasks inside), but you are talking it about as turn≈Task, reading the docs again carefully, I think I should edit my answer. But why the docs use the phrase turn if it means Task?

Comment: Sure thing, I added a comment to your answer :) I consider a turn to be a unit of synchronous work. It just so happens that for a TaskScheduler, that unit is represented by a (runnable) Task, and under the hood it's really a delegate. It would be worth writing detailed documentation on the design of the task scheduler, since it has changed over time: as recently as 2.1 when we merged a new implementation for the underlying worker pool.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this is a contrived code snippet that was written to explore the execution guarantees of the Orleans runtime. I'm a little concerned that somebody might read this and misconstrued that this is a recommended pattern of how grain methods should be implemented.

That's why I'd like to stress that the recommended way of writing grain code is to await every `Task` in the call stack. In the above code it would mean awaiting `x` in the grain method and `t` in the client code. By default grains are non-reentrant, and that would prevent a second call from the client to start executing before execution of the first one is completed. Or one might choose to mark the grain class as `[Reentrant]` and allow interleaving of a second call. That would be much more clear and explicit than the background loop, and would make error handling possible.

Comment: I understand your concern. I will change the question to highlight this point right at the beginning.